# jQuery: get image height + add padding if needed

Tags: jquery, css

I have a Bootstrap carousel with images of various heights. I'm want to center the images vertically. I'm trying to get the image height, subtract it from a constant height, and if it is below the constant, assign it padding-top equal to half the difference.

Here's my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.item img").each(function() {
        var maxHeight = 400;
        var imgHeight = $(this)[0].naturalHeight;
        if (imgHeight < maxHeight) {
            topPad = (maxHeight - imgHeight)/2;
            $(this).css("padding-top","topPad + px");
        }
    });
});
```

The topPad is being calculated correctly, but no CSS is getting added to the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an issue in this line `$(this).css("padding-top","topPad + px");`

`topPad` is a var therefore no `""` around the word

and you need to change this from `$(document).ready(function() {}` to `$(window).load(function() {}` so the calcs are made when all the images are fully loaded

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("div.item img").each(function() {
    var maxHeight = 400;
    var imgHeight = $(this)[0].naturalHeight;
    if (imgHeight < maxHeight) {
      topPad = (maxHeight - imgHeight) / 2;
      $(this).css("padding-top", topPad + "px");
      console.log(topPad, $(this)[0].src)
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-flex
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"><img src="//lorempixel.com/100/500" alt=""></div>
<div class="item"><img src="//lorempixel.com/100/300" alt=""></div>
<div class="item"><img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks for your help.